# combination question ASAP required

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Hi Can someone help me solve this please?

> In the clock game Alice and Bob both start at 12 o’ clock. During a
>   move Alice moves 5 hours clockwise on the clock-face and Bob moves 9
>   hours counterclockwise. How many moves will it take before Bob and
>   Alice stop on the same hour? What if the game is changes so that Alice
>   moves a hours clockwise and Bob moves b hours counterclockwise?

Comment: Is this really,  really urgent?

Comment: umm its okay by tomorrow

Comment: We do charge extra for speedy answers, you know...

Comment: oh ok, am i going to be charged for this?

Comment: :/ ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: :) :) :) :) :) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, we need to come up with an expression to describe the clock game using ["clock math"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic)(modular arithmetic).

Alice moves clockwise by 5 hours each time. The first few hours she lands on are
5, 10, 3, 8. The hour that she lands on after k turns is $A = 5k \bmod 12$.

Bob moves counterclockwise by nine hours each time. The first few hours Bob lands on are 3, 6, 9, 12, 3. The hour that he lands on after k turns is $\:B = (12 - 9)k \bmod 12 =  3k \bmod 12$.

So the question is asking, when does A = B or when is $5k \equiv 3k\bmod{12}$?

$$\begin{align}
5k &\equiv 3k \bmod 12\\
5k &= 3k + 12t \\
2k &= 12t \\
k &= 6t \\ 
\end{align}
$$

where $t = 1,2,3, ...$

So Alice and Bob land on the same hour when k = 6t; 6, 12, 18 ...
The first time they meet is after 6 turns.

Can you solve it for the case where Alice moves $a$ steps and Bob moves $b$ steps?

Hint: Now $A = ak \bmod{12}$ and $B = (12-b)k \bmod{12}$

Answer (score 0):

Draw it on a paper: a circle with $12$ points, and count it yourself. They should meet within $12$ rounds.

Comment: Thankyou I will try doing that

Comment: How do i find the a and b? @berci

Comment: Say, they start at the point $12$ o'clock, call it $0$, then, after the first round, Alice will be at $+5$, and Bob will be at $-9$. Since it is a clock, stepping $9$ counterclockwise is the same as stepping $3$ clockwise. So, Bob will be at $3$ o'clock after the first round. Second round: $A$ will be at $10$ o'clock, $B$ will be at $6$ o'clock. And so on..

Answer (score 0):

If both arrows are at the same position then they will have travelled a distance that is a multiple of 12. Since the distance travelled after $k$ moves is $9k+5k=14k$ we must have that $12$ divides $14k$. The smallest candidate $k$ for this is $6$. And it works.